# How to set button images based on browser type

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I'm using ASP.NET with a C# backend, and want to have a site show different images for mobile and desktop version.  I figured I could do this with CSS, but can't figure out how.  I have the different css files set up and working for other elements, but for these ImageButtons, I have some bad behavior.  If I don't set the ImageUrl attribute, it does what I need but puts "Search" and a gray outline around my buttons since it is looking for the nonexistent ImageUrl Path.  If I do set the ImageUrl attribute as shown below, the text and box go away, but the image won't change as I need them to.  I have tried this with a and img tags and LinkButtons but have gotten the same results both ways.  What is the best way to change the size and image of these buttons if the user is accessing via a mobile device?

```
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="button1" runat="server" CssClass="button1" 
    OnCommand="ImageButton_Click" CommandName="button1" 
    ImageUrl="~/images/topbutton1.png"/>
    ...
    <asp:ImageButton ID="button4" runat="server" CssClass="button4" 
    OnCommand="ImageButton_Click" CommandName="button1" 
    ImageUrl="~/images/topbutton4.png"/>
</div>
```

CSS classes look like this:

Normal:

```
.topbutton1
{
    padding: 0px 2px;
    background-image: url('../images/topbutton1.png');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline;
    width: 180px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Mobile:

```
.topbutton1
{
    padding: 0px 2px;
    background-image: url('../images/topbutton1mobile.png');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This will help you in general with your mobile layout needs: http://designshack.net/articles/css/quick-tips-for-creating-a-mobile-optimized-site/

Comment: Are you using asp.net C#  ? This is how to detect browser type `System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS media queries to switch the image based on screen size:

[Introduction to CSS Media Queries](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html)

Comment: Although I ultimately scrapped the image altogether for mobile, this was ultimately part of my solution.  Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Media queries are by far the simplest method - sniffing browser agent strings is hacky at best...